# How to open file in Mozilla Add-on SDK using system default application

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to initiate opening file in system default application in [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) environment, or at least in Firefox plugin in general?

I'm looking for multi-platform solution, so I'd rather avoid things like **platform detection + `require("sdk/system/child_process").exec()` + (`open`, `xdg-open`, `RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL`).**

Something like [Desktop#open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File) from Java world would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is method [nsIFile#launch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFile). Instance of nsIFile based on file path can be obtained using [FileUtils#File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm) constructor.

Following code demonstrates usage  of `launch` method to open home directory in default file browser in Add-on SDK code.

```js
var homeDir = require('sdk/system').pathFor('Home');
require('chrome').Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
new FileUtils.File(homeDir).launch();
```