# Execute .jar file with a Mozilla extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, jpm

I have looked at the following questions that were answered here:

[How to open file in Mozilla Add-on SDK using system default application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314232/how-to-open-file-in-mozilla-add-on-sdk-using-system-default-application/26315005#26315005)

[How can I open an external app from Firefox addon? (Eg: default text editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754621/how-can-i-open-an-external-app-from-firefox-addon-eg-default-text-editor/16756328#16756328)

[Perfom a ShellExecute from Firefox Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138536/perfom-a-shellexecute-from-firefox-addon/25140717#25140717)

yet none of these solutions have worked for me and I feel the problem may be deeper than I originally thought. Essentially I am trying to launch a .jar executable with a Mozilla add-on extension. My code looks like the following:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "execute-jar",
  label: "Download Report",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});



function handleClick(state) {
    // try {
        // var file = Services.dirsvc.get("Desk", Ci.nsIFile);
        // file.append("C:\Users\QaziWa\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
        // file.launch();
    // }
    // catch (ex) {
        // console.error("failure");
      // Failed to launch because e.g. the OS returned an error
      // or the file does not exist,
      // or this function is simply not implemented for a particular platform.
    // }

    let {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
    var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath("C:\Users\QaziWa\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
    console.log(file);
    if(file.exists()){
        file.reveal();
        file.launch();
    }
    else {
        console.log('Failed.');
    }
}
```

For some odd reason my .jar file is not detected and I can't understand why. I was hoping someone could offer any input as to why this may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
file.initWithPath("C:\Users\QaziWa\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
```

to

```
file.initWithPath("C:\\Users\\QaziWa\\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
```

Need to escape those slashes ;)

Comment: Haha you posted this just as I was about to answer my own question. Thank you for the post however!

Comment: My pleasure man keep up the great work, looking forward to seeing your addon as finished product.